# twitter rest api v 1.1 in flash application + php

Tags: php, actionscript-3, codeigniter, twitter, flash-cs5

First, I've create a app twitter and read the documentation that the rest api v1.0 will not supported(available) longer and the new one is v1.1

Then, I've develop a flash app that utilize twitter by retrieve user's profile and that profile will be the base for data comparison process.

How I can build a sign-in twitter mechanism so when the user succesfully sign-in the apps get the profile data and will do some comparison mechanism? Is ther any tutorial about this especially work around with twitter rest api v1.1?

And what about consumer key, consumer secret, Access token secret, Access token?

Sorry if ask a lot questions because some tutorial I found in internet not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

So far I have only found the following library in github.com, but yet to decipher the usage of the library:

https://github.com/susisu/Twitter-for-AS3